# Excel-Levenshtein algorithm applied on column

Tags: python, r, excel, algorithm

I am trying to use Levenshtein algorithm to find similarities between records. 
What i have is column of Item#, description, LookUp, Similarity(%),ReturnSimilarItem. In the column Description i have few different description, in the lookUp item i will have similar values to values in Description column. Using Levenshtein function i want to identify similarity and if is over 90% i want to return the value from Item# column that is attached to the similar item.See picture for better description. 
[image]
And here is the code for Levenshtein i am using:

```
Function Levenshtein3(ByVal string1 As String, ByVal string2 As String) As Long

Dim i As Long, j As Long, string1_length As Long, string2_length As Long
Dim distance(0 To 60, 0 To 50) As Long, smStr1(1 To 60) As Long, smStr2(1 To 
50) As Long
Dim min1 As Long, min2 As Long, min3 As Long, minmin As Long, MaxL As Long

string1_length = Len(string1):  string2_length = Len(string2)

distance(0, 0) = 0
For i = 1 To string1_length:    distance(i, 0) = i: smStr1(i) = 
Asc(LCase(Mid$(string1, i, 1))): Next
For j = 1 To string2_length:    distance(0, j) = j: smStr2(j) = 
Asc(LCase(Mid$(string2, j, 1))): Next
For i = 1 To string1_length
    For j = 1 To string2_length
        If smStr1(i) = smStr2(j) Then
        distance(i, j) = distance(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
        min1 = distance(i - 1, j) + 1
        min2 = distance(i, j - 1) + 1
        min3 = distance(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
        If min2 < min1 Then
            If min2 < min3 Then minmin = min2 Else minmin = min3
        Else
            If min1 < min3 Then minmin = min1 Else minmin = min3
        End If
        distance(i, j) = minmin
        End If
    Next
Next

' Levenshtein3 will properly return a percent match (100%=exact) based on 
 similarities and Lengths etc...
 MaxL = string1_length: If string2_length > MaxL Then MaxL = string2_length
 Levenshtein3 = 100 - CLng((distance(string1_length, string2_length) * 100)    
/ MaxL)

End Function
```

How do i make it to use look up value from C3 and look through entire B column and once it find the item that is similar over 90% return the Item# attached to that description?

Is this easier to do in Python on R ?

Comment: If this is for code in an excel worksheet, it is not VB.NET at all.

Comment: In R it is virtually certain that there is at least one package on CRAN for this. On the other hand, there is no reason that it can't be properly implemented in VBA. If the data is in Excel and you want to use it in Excel, using VBA is natural.

Comment: You loop through each entry in column B, and return the adjacent column A when it meets your criteria.  Consider that you may want to exclude the identical entry; and also how you want to handle multiple items that meet the criteria.

Comment: I would copy `LookUp` for all of your `Description`s. This way you can see the score for every `Description` and manually inspect the ones that exceed some threshold. The `stringdist` package in R does this. If you're already in Excel and your data are a manageable size, then I see no need to switch. Visually inspecting your matches will be easier in Excel assuming the data are small enough that visually inspection is feasible.

Comment: I have over 1M of rows and close to 30 columns in original excel sheet. I am  trying to work with subset of that data including just Item# and descriptions and lookUp to make it more efficient while im developing this. But i am pretty stuck right now.

Comment: With that scale you might want to consider using R. It can be called from Excel using the RExcel add-in. The stringdist package is written in C, which will yield the sort of speed that you need for 1M rows: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf